# Failed reCAPTCHA. Please try again

Tags: recaptcha, captcha

I have a problem.
All time I surfed the WEB I never had problem with reCAPTCHA.
But today, when I was solving reCAPTCHAs - I always have the same error "Failed reCAPTCHA. Please try again".
And I can not pass through this "gate".

I tried to restart the browser (google chrome), tried to clear browser cache, tried to restart PC. I even tried to use VPN (I do not know how this could help, but for the sake of luck I tried this too).
So.. maybe stackoverflow is not the place, where I should ask help about this problem, but unfortunately Google has no inner forums or feedback fields. So I ask about help here.

Did anyone ever meet this problem? And how can it be fixed?
Help me, please. I encountered this problem first time in my life.

Comment: What do you mean by "solving reCAPTCHAs"?

Comment: Hi!
I mean next: 9 pictures appear on the screen and I should check everyone which matches the condition "bridges/motocycles/cars/traffic lights.."
And when I select all correct pictures which match condition - this means "solving reCAPTCHAs"

Comment: @ScottHunter by the way, I noticed today that only some sites have such strange problem. For example, when I was creating this topic at stackoverflow, I also should solve reCAPTCHA task, but everything was without any problem and I could post this thread

Comment: How is this a programming problem?

Comment: Well, it is not directly programming problem. But I needed solution of this problem for intergrating of my code on some sites with reCAPTCHA.

ps.
This is how problem was solved: I wrote directly to sites' support, and tech teams updated some settings on their side. And now reCAPTCHA at these sites (at least which I needed) works correctly.

pps. I wrote about this problem at stackoverflow, because I had not feedback from tech teams during long time and I searched for alternative solutions.

Sorry for disturbance. And thank you for your feedback, @ScottHunter

Comment: So you were asking for a way to hack someone else's site; otherwise, how would any programming by you even be *indirecty* involved?